# Expo ScreenOrientation.lockAsync() Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm building a React Native app using Expo.  I'm attempting to have a screen display in Landscape mode.  Without the call to `lockAsync`, everything works fine.  When adding the call to `lockAsync`, the screen correctly rotates, but then I get a React warning followed shortly thereafter by `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect`

```
const Temp = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    changeScreenOrientation();
  }, []);

  const changeScreenOrientation = async () => {
    await lockAsync(OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>test</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.pop()} title="back" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The useEffect call is only happening once, so something is causing an infinite loop or error when calling `lockAsync`

ExceptionsManager.js:126 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

169ExceptionsManager.js:126 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect